# SVPullToRefresh custom view causes layoutIfNeeded go into infinite loop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I tried using custom views for the SVPullToRefresh but I've stumbled upon weird issue. I've made the demo project to illustrate the issue: https://github.com/gaks/SVRefreshProblem

The project is simply one UITableViewController with a TableView and the xib file with custom refresh bar view. The SVPullToRefresh is added to the tableView via the IBOutlet in the viewDidLoad: https://github.com/gaks/SVRefreshProblem/blob/master/SVRefreshProblem/DemoViewController.m

There is also a code that loads the RefreshBarView from the xib file and sets it as a custom view for SVPullToRefresh (for 'loading' state only for illustration):

```
RefreshBarView* refreshBarView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RefreshBarView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
refreshBarView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);

[[tableView pullToRefreshView] setCustomView:refreshBarView forState:SVPullToRefreshStateLoading];
```

The issue is that when you pull the table view to trigger the refresh it goes into infinite loop and eat-all-available-memory state after calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]` in the `- (void)setState:(SVPullToRefreshState)newState`. As far as I was able to debug it keeps calling `- (void)layoutSubviews` over and over.

What's weird is that when you open the xib file: https://github.com/gaks/SVRefreshProblem/blob/master/SVRefreshProblem/SVPullToRefresh/RefreshBarView.xib
... and remove the label from the view - it works just fine (except you have an empty view).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Loading from nibs is for ViewControllers, not views proper.  You can try to do this programmatically which will work :

```
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
    [label setText:@"asdf"];
    [v addSubview:label];
    [[tableView pullToRefreshView] setCustomView:v forState:SVPullToRefreshStateLoading];
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine but it requires designing the view from code. The only reason I tried to use xib is so I can design the view in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off "Use Auto Layout" in your nib.